React App - Browser out of memory crashing
I have a redux store which has an array of 100 and then I have incoming data that’s like an array of 200 which appends to the existing array of 100 and this happens every second . (Real time data)
We are already diffing so I was thinking web worker/batching
We are doing […array1,..array2] which seems like a deep copy, I could try to do something else. (Batching feels like it would just delay the issue)(all this is to avoid my browser crashing with out of memory error)(after like 7 min ish looking at the memory in my dev tool it’s like 1800gb)
I will be using React Memo and do some quick performance easy win but this feels like it’s more. I’ve reach the limit and I’m not sure if this requires significantly more work or if there are some other things I can do or something I’m missing.
Is using web worker in react to continuously be merging old data with new data be an option?
Thanks really appreciate any suggestion or help
